# How to make circle as table using konva react

Tags: reactjs, konvajs

Need help, how to make custom circle like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDq0N.png)

and will adjust to the middle circle (the big circle) if I add a small circle as the chair.
iam using konvaJS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats your effort doing that, where are you stuck in you effort ??

Comment: because I want to create a table and chair system for an event such as the chair and table drawing system on the eventbrite website

https://www.eventbrite.com/create/seat-map

Comment: the idea is like, the big circle one as the table and the small cricle as the chair, and the chair (small circle) added by input chairs amount by user..

more chairs, it will adjust to the big circle (table) and remain circular

Comment: Hi - if my answer was correct please could you mark it as the correct answer by clicking the tick. Marking the correct or most helpful answer helps other people judge its relevance and awards points to the answerer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a plain JS solution to the question about adding seats and moving current seats appropriately. The math is simple - divide 360 by the number of seats to get the angle for each seat then iterate per seat calculating the X, Y position via the angle math, noting that JS Math lib works in radians.  Hopefully you can wrangle this into reactjs.

Snipped best viewed full screen. Also available at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/YzqWqjN?editors=0011)

```js
// These are the main parameters of the image
let seats = 4, tableRadius = 150;
const radmult = Math.PI / 180;

// Set up a stage
let stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: 500
      }),

    // add a layer to draw on
    seatLayer = new Konva.Layer(),
    

    tableLayer = new Konva.Layer(),

    // Add a circle to act as the table
    tableCircle = new Konva.Circle({name: 'table', x: 200, y: 200, radius: 120, fill: 'magenta', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 4 });

    // Add a circle to act as a positioner for the seats.
    seatPos = new Konva.Circle({name: 'seatPos', x: 200, y: 200, radius: 150, fill: 'transparent', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 4 });
    
 tableLayer.add(tableCircle);
 seatLayer.add(seatPos);
 stage.add(seatLayer);
 stage.add(tableLayer);

// function to lay out the seats
function layout() {

  let angle = 360 / (seats);

  // Clear current seats
  var shapes = seatLayer.find('.seat').destroy();
  
  // draw new seats
  for (var i = 0; i < seats; i++){

    let posAngle = angle * i,
        x = 200 + (tableRadius * Math.sin(posAngle * radmult)), 
        y = 200 + (tableRadius * Math.cos(posAngle * radmult));

    let c = new Konva.Circle({name: 'seat', x: x, y: y, radius: 40, fill: 'cyan', stroke: 'black', strokeWidth: 4});
      
    seatLayer.add(c);

  }
  
  seatLayer.draw();
}

// initial draw so we can see something
layout();
stage.draw()

// Listeners on buttons to add & remove seats
$('#add').on('click', function(){
  
  seats = seats + 1;
  layout();
  
})

$('#remove').on('click', function(){
  
  if (seats > 0) {
    seats = seats - 1;
    layout();
  }
  
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/7.0.3/konva.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^3/konva.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <button id = 'add'>Add seat</button>
  <button id = 'remove'>Remove seat</button>

</p>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I was able to draw a table and chairs just like that. but I also wanted to make the set of both draggable. Any idea how to add one dragstart event to drag the whole set of that table and chairs?